# why can't I see any model after load a fbx file?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm developing a web system using three.js.

After I load a fbx file, I can not see any model in the scene.

then there is no error code in the console, shows just this

```
THREE.FBXLoader: FBX binary version: 7400
```

could someone please help to solve this case?

Thank you in advance.

---

main.js code

```
window.addEventListener('load', init);

function init() {
  const width = 960;
  const height = 540;

  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: document.querySelector('#myCanvas')
  });
  renderer.setSize(width, height);

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
  scene.add(light);

  const loader = new THREE.FBXLoader();
  loader.load('static/fbx/dennis.fbx', (object) => {
    scene.add(object);
  });

  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, width / height);
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 1000);

  const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

  tick();

  function tick() {

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(tick);
  }
}
```

HTML code

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>threejs Test</title>
    <!-- my_css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/mystyle.css">
</head>

<body>
<h1>test</h1>
<div class="canvas_wrapper">
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
<!-- three.js_js -->
<script src="static/js/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/FBXLoader.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/inflate.min.js"></script>
<!-- my_js -->
<script src="static/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

version: three.js r116

Comment: Hi ! I think it's juste a bad placement in your HTML. FBXLoader and inflate.min.js should be call before the main.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment, I tried changing the js file order in my HTML as your advice and edit my code in question, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Ok, looks good for me, just add `document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);` before `tick()`.

Comment: And I think you don't need `window.addEventListener('load', init);`

Comment: @MlleBz , I added 'document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);' before 'tick()' and removed 
'window.addEventListener('load', init);' but it still doesn't work...

Comment: @MlleBz, And when I removed "window.addEventListener('load', init); ", I can not seen either..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Humm... can you copy/paste this code and tell me what you see ?
It's working for me.

```
window.addEventListener('load', init);

init();

function init() {
  const width = 960;
  const height = 540;

  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: document.querySelector('#myCanvas')
  });
  renderer.setSize(width, height);

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
  scene.add(light);

  const loader = new THREE.FBXLoader();
  loader.load("static/fbx/dennis.fbx", function(object) {
    scene.add(object);
  });

  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, width / height);
  camera.position.set(0, 200, 100);

  const plane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(200, 200), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xff0000, side: THREE.DoubleSide }));
  plane.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
  scene.add(plane);

  let controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  controls.update();

  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  tick();
  function tick() {
    requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
}
```

I always add a plane to be sure to see something ^^

Comment: Hi MlleBz, thank you for your answer, this time I can see the fbx model as small size, so the reason why I couldn't see the model was that the size of model is too small.

Comment: Cool ! You can rescale your model before adding it in the scene with : `object.scale.multiplyScalar(10);` or `object.scale.set(10, 10, 10);`